# Disable Same Origin Policy in TWebbrowser

Tags: javascript, delphi, internet-explorer, same-origin-policy

I'm currently creating a demo-application for our software, and it's basically a website, just delivered inside a delphi-application which works with a TWebbrowser to prevents the user from doing unnecessary things.
I've embedded some youtube-videos via tubeplayer-plugin, and because of that I get error-dialogs related to the "Same Origin Policy".

In IE, normally there is an option to disable this policy, is there any way to do this for the TWebbrowser? ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947359/disable-same-origin-policy-internet-explorer) for the option I'm referring to)

If not I'd also be glad to hear other ideas on how to prevent this error messages (I can't change the code which causes the errors, so please don't tell me to use Cross-Site-Requests).

---

Edit:
I know the "silent"-option of TWebbrowser, but the error also causes my component to misbehave, so this isn't a real solution for my problem...

Comment: Did you analyze the HTTP traffic and Javascript console (if available) to find out which part causes the SOP error message? As Youtube can be embedded in other web pages, I do not think that the embedded Youtube object is the cause of the problem. This leaves the tubeplayer plugin as a potential cause. Is tubeplayer required?

Comment: Using the normal embedding would be my last resort, because i really like the features tubeplayer provides... and yeah, the error comes from inside the plugin, but I dont have the sources so I'm not sure what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Look at FEATURE_CROSS DOMAIN_REDIRECT_MITIGATION in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#xd_redirection
There it explains how you can disable the option for your application in the registry. Adding some delphi code to do that automatically in HKEY_CURRENT_USER when your application starts should do the trick. Good luck.