# Fill two input fields in a webpage

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I've written a script in VBA in combination with IE to fill two input fields to login to a webpage.

When I try to execute my script, it throws ***`Access is denied`*** error because of the `iframe` within which the input fields are. How can I fill the two input fields with my credentials?

[This is the site link](http://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/team?leagueId=24874190&teamId=1&statSplit=currSeason)

This is my try so far:

```
Sub LogIn()
    Const Url = "replace with above link"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim frm As Object, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Set frm = HTML.querySelector("iframe[name='disneyid-iframe']").contentWindow.document
    Set post = frm.querySelector("input[placeholder='Username or Email Address']")
    post.Value = "somename@gmailmail.com"
End Sub
```

You can try with any input details. All I need to know is how can I fill  the two boxes.

Html elements connected to `iframe` content:

```
<iframe id="disneyid-secure-responder" name="disneyid-secure-responder" src="https://www.espn.com/disneyid/responder/index.html?clientId=ESPN-ONESITE.WEB-PROD&amp;scheme=http&amp;postMessageOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Ffantasy.espn.com%2Fbasketball%2Fteam%3FleagueId%3D24874190%26teamId%3D1%26statSplit%3DcurrSeason&amp;cookieDomain=espn.com&amp;config=PROD&amp;logLevel=INFO&amp;topHost=fantasy.espn.com&amp;ageBand=ADULT&amp;countryCode=CA&amp;langPref=en-US&amp;cssOverride=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.espncdn.com%2Fcombiner%2Fc%3Fcss%3Ddisneyid%2Fcore.css%2Cdisneyid%2Ffantasy.css&amp;responderPage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.espn.com%2Fdisneyid%2Fresponder%2Findex.html&amp;buildId=165f40c7564" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, the iframe `src` is in a different domain and [same domain policy](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/bypassing-same-origin-policy-sop/#gref) effectively rules out IE for > version 8 in this case. Whilst messing with security settings to attempt to bypass this is a bad idea see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947359/disable-same-origin-policy-internet-explorer) for reading.

This is easy enough with [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) for VBA using Chrome. You additionally need to loop until login details can be entered. I add a timeout to prevent an infinite loop.

After installing selenium you need to go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to Selenium Type Library.

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub Login()
    Dim d As WebDriver, ele As WebElement, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Const url = "http://fantasy.espn.com/basketball/team?leagueId=24874190&teamId=1&statSplit=currSeason"
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            .SwitchToFrame .FindElementById("disneyid-iframe")
            Set ele = .FindElementByCss("[type=email]")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While Not ele.IsDisplayed

        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        ele.SendKeys "Bob@Builder.com"
        .FindElementByCss("[type=password]").SendKeys "password"
        .FindElementByCss("[type=submit]").Click

        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        'Other code
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works smoothly but the thing is I need to accomplish this using vba IE @QHarr. Plus one for your nice script. Thanks.

Comment: I knew this question might arise lol. Right you are @QHarr, I need to do it without selenium.

Comment: Humm.... I don't think you can as stated below. The same origin policy governs whether you can transition into the next frame and use it. That, I believe, basically rules out IE in fact where you have a different domain src for the iframe. There are some hacks shown on SO - whether they work via VBA and IE - I think unlikely.

Comment: I tried with post request but the thing is I could not make use of `api-key` within headers.

Comment: That sounds like a new question to keep the two methods separate. Do you have the API documentation and your own key? Can you share just the documentation link?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. What i meant is I go for IE only when I can't solve using xmlhttp request. I just informed you that I tried all possible angles to avoid selenium. Btw, the `api-key` generates dynamically.

Comment: ok... let me have a look at the documentation... a dynamic API key?

Comment: btw if you deal with Python have you seen this? https://stmorse.github.io/journal/espn-fantasy-python.html

Comment: Can you share API docu link?

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer example below may solve your issue.

Main HTML Page Code (demo51.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<H2>This is main page...</h2><br>
<iframe src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\demo52.html" id="ifrm" height="300px" width="300px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Page which will be displayed with in Main page Iframe (demo52.html).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2> Sample Page</h2><br>
Name: <input type="text" id="txt_name" value=""><br><br>
Age: &nbsp &nbsp<input type="text" id="txt_age" value=""><br><br>
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

VBA Code:

```html
Public Sub demo()

Dim baseURL As String
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim workFrame As HTMLIFrame
Dim acctInput As HTMLInputElement

baseURL = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\demo51.html"

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

With IE
.Visible = True



.Navigate baseURL
While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend



Set workFrame = .Document.getElementById("ifrm")
Set HTMLdoc = workFrame.contentWindow.Document
End With

Set acctInput = HTMLdoc.getElementById("txt_name")
acctInput.Focus
acctInput.Value = "abcde"

Set acctInput = HTMLdoc.getElementById("txt_age")
acctInput.Focus
acctInput.Value = "25"

End Sub
```

Output in Internet Explorer:

[image]

**Note:** Try to add reference to library below in VBA Editor.

(1) Microsoft HTML Object Library.

(2) Microsoft Internet controls.

Try to change the URL in code as per your own requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change things in an iframe on another domain due to security limitations.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Is this the solution or a comment @Engel?

Comment: Well it's not really a solution but the answer is "you can't".