# use vba to download report from password protected web but internet explorer report SEC7131: Security of a sandboxed iframe to stop inserting texts

Tags: html, vba

Need to download a lot of report from this password-protected web and would like to use excel VBA to download them automatically.

under internet explorer, I log in with my username and password opened the webpage manually, and tried to use Excel VBA to enter parameters to download the report, but had no success (no text entered) and kept receiving the message: SEC7131: Security of a sandboxed iframe is potentially compromised by allowing script and same-origin access.

I applied the same code on Google and was able to enter text in the Google search bar.

Some people said to disable same-origin policy by enabling access to data sources from the domain. ([How to disable same origin policy Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947359/how-to-disable-same-origin-policy-internet-explorer)) I did, not working neither.

Could anyone give me some guide?

Comment: How is the password-protection implemented, exactly? A login form? HTTP Basic, Digest, NTLM/Kerberos Auth?

Comment: Hi , it is a web based accounting software. I login in with password and tried to use vba to download report. in the same web, the header reacted with vba code, clicking, entering text in search bar, but the core part where I need to enter parameter to get the report does not react with vba code and gave me the error : CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.  maybe my user does not have authorization ?